# Spring security + JWT 403 forbidden error

Tags: spring, security, jwt

So, i'm trying to secure an api with SpringSecurity and JWT tokens. I can obtain the token but every time i try to access a protected endpoint using the token i get a 403 Forbidden.  I have a DB containing roles and users. 
Here is my spring security config :

```
 httpSecurity.csrf().disable().cors().disable()
            // dont authenticate this particular request
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate", "/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/system/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            //.antMatchers("/system").permitAll()
            // all other requests need to be authenticated
                    //.anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and().
            // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
            // store user's state.
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
    httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

I tried debugging, and the token can be decoded, the user infomations can be accessed and a user object containing roles can be obtained. That's why i don't really have an idea of what's going on .

[image: Debugging vars :]

And here's my filtering method from RequestFilter class :

```
String username = null;
String jwtToken = null;
// JWT Token is in the form "Bearer token". Remove Bearer word and get
// only the Token
if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
    try {
        username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
    }
} else {
    logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
}       // Once we get the token validate it.
if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {           UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);          // if token is valid configure Spring Security to manually set
    // authentication
    if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        // After setting the Authentication in the context, we specify
        // that the current user is authenticated. So it passes the
        // Spring Security Configurations successfully.
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
    }
}
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Sorry for this long message :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to prefix the `SimpleGrantedAuthority` with `ROLE_`.
Add something like this in your `UserDetailsService`.

```
String ROLE_PREFIX = "ROLE_";
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(ROLE_PREFIX + user.getRole()));
```

Comment: And keeping hasRole("ADMIN") in the securityconfig ?

Comment: Still, I am getting 403

Answer (score 1):

In your security config instead of:

```
    hasRole("ADMIN")
```

try:

```
    hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
```